# Export / Download a local file to device UNITY

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assets

I want to export / download / save a file to my device after clicking a button in Unity. Trying to create an Android application here. The file will most probably be a binary file, either a .PDF or .JPG (since they will just be the same). How do I do this?

If ever there is no way that I can do something like that via c#? Is there any other way of doing this? How about saving a file directly after installation of the APK? Thank you

Comment: Have a look [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/download-a-file-from-url-and-save-it-to-persistentdatapath.520817/).